# escaping apostrophe within data elements in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
currRow = currRow + '<td><a href="#" onclick="viewTCsystem(' + data['DATA']['SYSTEM_ID'][i] + ',\''+ data['DATA']['SYSTEM_NAME'][i] + '\');">' + data['DATA']['SYSTEM_NAME'][i] + '</a></td>...
```

An example of what parameters should be (723,'Hammer's') with Hammer's as the link.

The problem lies in `system_names` that have an apostrophe. Not sure how to escape the apostrophe and keep single quotes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're allowed to use double-quotes, which solves this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var _id = data['DATA']['SYSTEM_ID'][i].replace("'","\'");
var _data = data['DATA']['SYSTEM_NAME'][i].replace("'","\'");
currRow = currRow + '<td><a href="#" onclick="viewTCsystem(' + _id + ',\''+ _data + '\');">' + _data + '</a></td>...
```

unless I'm misinterpreting what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use various methods:

```
str = "Foo's bar";
str = 'Foo\'s bar';
```

Both are good, but maybe the cleaner is the first one.
So, your code would become:

```
currRow = currRow + '<td><a href=# onclick=\'viewTCsystem(' + data['DATA']['SYSTEM_ID'][i] + ',"' + data['DATA']['SYSTEM_NAME'][i] + '");\'>' + data['DATA']['SYSTEM_NAME'][i] + '</a></td>';
```

We have just inverted the two types of quotes.

### Better:

By the way you should really take a look to some template system like Mustache or Jade

With Mustache it would becomes:

```
{{#DATA}}
  <td><a href="#" onclick="viewTCsystem({{SYSTEM_ID}}, '{{SYSTEM_NAME}}');">{{SYSTEM_NAME}}</a></td>
{{/DATA}}
```

Where `DATA` is:

```
var DATA = {
   {SYSTEM_ID: 01, SYSTEM_NAME: "Foo's"},
   {SYSTEM_ID: 02, SYSTEM_NAME: "Bar's"}
};
```

### Much better:

Again, would be better have markup and logic separated, so it could become:

```
{{#DATA}}
  <td><a href="#" class="view-tc-system" data-id ="{{SYSTEM_ID}}" data-name="{{SYSTEM_NAME}}">{{SYSTEM_NAME}}</a></td>
{{/DATA}}
```

jQuery:

```
function handleViewTCsystem() {
    viewTCsystem($(this).data("id"), $(this).data("name"));
}

$(document).on("click", ".view-tc-system", handleViewTCsystem);
```

### Most important thing:

You should REALLY escape the entire name to avoid any kind of conflict or JS injection (XSS).

The first thing that hits my mind is the functions `btoa()` and `atob()`.
You may make the string safe with `btoa(SYSTEM_NAME)` and then in your `viewTcSystem()` convert it back with `atob(SYSTEM_NAME)`

Answer (score 0):

For a JS literal replace all `'` with `\'` (escaping the `\` for the RegEx);

```
 thing = thing.replace(/\'/g, '\\\'')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears that the string is coming from an external source you could use the `.replace` method.

```
data['DATA']['SYSTEM_NAME'][i].replace("'","\'")
```